# Text fade-in animations with a different fillMode. I.E. Show the words from a paragraph one by one

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-animation, fade

Apple only gives us these options:

```
kCAFillModeRemoved
kCAFillModeForwards
kCAFillModeBackwards
kCAFillModeBoth
```

But I wish we could get all the possibilities we have in keynote, in particular the one I am looking for, is the animation that shows the words of a paragraph one by one in the period of 2 seconds. Is this possible?

Thank you so much.

Alejandro

Comment: That's not really what these full modes are referring to.

Comment: Oh really? Do you have any ideas to solve this problem? :-)

Comment: You have to write the different animations yourself (or find someone who has already done it) and add them to the label/labels in some way. You maybe do it with custom animatable properties, maybe with different labels for each word or maybe with Core Text or Text Kit but it's not going to be easy.